# (#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-media

I got this error when my web application try to post to my page at Facebook.  It was working fine up till last Thursday 1/19/2012.  I have checked my Stream post URL security as suggested in other thread, it is set to disable.  Thus, I should not have problem.  Is there any other setting I missed.  I am pretty sure it is due to Facebook app configuration because I try to do the same thing using Facebook graph explorer and get the same error.

I make http post call https://graph.facebook.com/my_page_id/feed with following parameter
  message, link, access_token

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your connect URL and base domain in your application settings. I have previously had errors from the FB.UI dialog that prevented wall posts because I had not set my site URL.

If required I believe you can set your site URL to be the URL of your canvas or page tab application.